# Unable to use the bootstrap togglable tabs using ruby (link_to) method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty in getting the bootstrap [togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)  element to work using the `link_to` view helper method. This is the bootstrap code i want to implement:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried the following, but have not gotten a successful result:

```html
<div role="tabpanel">
 <ul id="my_menu a" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Main", root_path, :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
   <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path, :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
   <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path, :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
$('#my_menu a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
</script>
```

I can get the tabs to appear but nothing happens when I click on them. I hope the problem is clear enough. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why you have `"data-toggle" => "modal"` instead of tab here?

Comment: the ruby code i provided is just an example of the syntax i used to implement the code, not the actual code i wrote. the actual code i used is the following:  

    <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Main", root_path, :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>

Comment: yes I have used the code I provided the comment which corrects the issue you mentioned, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you give the `<ul>` an `ID` ? I do not see any `ID` in your `<ul>` element.

Comment: I just tried adding an id. still no luck. I updated the code in the main question to the what i currently have.

Comment: I would like to note that when I replace the (root_path) with a "#" the tabs seem to work. it is when I try to link them to the actual page where im having an issue.

Comment: @RashedAl-Julaibi, when you are using profile_path, you have to pass the profile object as a parameter, like this - profile_path(@profile).

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative solution which I found simpler:

You can add the basic classes to all the elements around the menu items while using the ruby `link_to` helpers and then use a ruby helper function to add the class active to the page you are currently on. This means the tabs display and are then correctly highlighted.

Eg in your nav.html.erb partial:

```
<nav class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="<%= cp(root_path)%>" role="presentation"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li class="<%= cp(user_list_path)%>" role="presentation"><%= link_to "All users", user_list_path, class: cp(user_list_path) %></li>
          <li class="<%= cp(my_profile_path)%>" role="presentation"><%= link_to "#{current_user.username}", my_profile_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and in your `application_helper.rb`

```
def cp(path)
      "active" if current_page?(path)
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually stopped working on that project a while ago, but I appreciate understanding a new approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually).

Add this in your application.js or corresponding js file:

```
$('#my_menu a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

and give your `<ul>` an `ID`:

```
<ul id="my_menu" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
```

---

**Update:**

Here is the complete snippet:

```
<div role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul id="my_menu" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Main", '#home', :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
      <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Profile", '#profile', :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
      <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Projects", '#messages', :role => "tab", :data => {:toggle => "tab"} %></li>
    </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#my_menu a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but still no luck. I updated the code in the question to show exactly what I currently have. I can get the tabs to appear, but clicking on them does nothing. I would like to note that when I replace the (root_path) with a "#" the tabs seem to work. it is when I try to link them to the actual page where im having an issue.

Comment: I tried you suggestion, unfortunately im still having the same problem. I even tried using the <a href=""> method but its giving me the same issue. the tabs only seem to work when I make a blank link "#".

Comment: is there a way you could access my files (with github?) to check my code and if there is something missing? im making a very basic web app, and its in the very early stages. I have only set the main pages for the nav bar so far. Im quite new to programming so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @RashedAl-Julaibi, you can not do what you are trying to do. You have to use anchor with '#', I have updated my answer. That is the last thing you can try.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing :(. anyway thanks for the help it is much appreciated!